# ActiveMQ - Dynamically changing the number of listeners

Tags: spring-jms

I am using ActiveMQ with Spring. It is easy to configure and start listening to messages.

One of my queues is defined as

```
<jms:listener-container container-type="default" 
                        connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                        acknowledge="auto">
    <jms:listener destination="RV_QUEUE" ref="webListener" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

All is good, but I would like to dynamically make some of the machines in our nodes to unregister themselves from ActiveMQ, in order to stop consuming messages.

I can make every machine listen for a signal. The question is, how can I make them register/unregister with AMQ?

Would I need to go back to creating my own sessions, and opening and closing them? Or is there a Spring way of doing it?

Comment: Try to be more clear: JMS or AMQP ? ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ ? And edit, please, your post for consistency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<jms:listener-container>` populates `AbstractJmsListeningContainer` beans for each `<jms:listener>` sub-element configuration. That container may be registered with explicit `id`.

From other side the `AbstractJmsListeningContainer` implements `SmartLifecycle`. So you can `start/stop` any Listener Container (with its Listener) any time by that `id` attribute:

```
beanFactory.getBean("myListener", Lifecycle.class).stop();
```

After stopping of the Listener Container, your Listener stops to consume messages from queue.

Comment: This is about how to stop listening dynamically. Any solution to register/add listener to start consuming messages?